# PHP while loop column in array

Tags: php

how can I loop the row with the array value which dynamically change?

instead of this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {        

echo "<tr><td align='left'>" . $row['english'] . "</td></tr>";  
echo "<tr><td align='left'>" . $row['spanish'] . "</td></tr>";  
echo "<tr><td align='left'>" . $row['italian'] . "</td></tr>";  
.
.
.          
      }
```

I need something like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) and $property = mysqli_fetch_field($result))
      {  
      $name = $property->name; // array?

      echo "<tr><td align='left'>" . $row[$name] . "</td></tr>";  

      }
```

Comment: Loop row or column ? Im confused

Comment: looping rows of an individual columns

Comment: We cannot help further until you,choose whether you wasn't column as asked in the title, or row as stated in question body

Comment: from the code it's clear what I mean!

Comment: @Grasper add inner loop `foraech($row as $column => $value)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add inner loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {    
    foreach($row as $column => $value) {
        // $column is column name 'englsih', 'spanish' etc.
        echo "<tr><td align='left'>" . $value . "</td></tr>";  
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work right. It doubles the same rows twice.

Comment: almost there. It just gives me the rows twice.

Comment: ok, I figured it out. Instead of mysqli_fetch_array, I need to use mysqli_fetch_row. Please edit you answer and I will check it. Thanks a lot for good direction...